# T SQL Convert a row to a string

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

Is there a valid way in SQL Server 2005 to read a row of data into a string?

For example if my table looked like the following:

```
ID | First Name | Last Name | Color
-----------------------------------
 1 | Timmy      | Jones     | pink
 2 | Martha     | Fisher    | green
```

That I could get back as a result:

```
'1 Timmy Jones pink'
'2 Martha Fisher green'
```

Preferably I could get back with the column name appended such as:

```
'ID: 1, First Name: Timmy, Last Name: Jones, Color: pink'
'ID: 2, First Name: Martha, Last Name: Fisher, Color: green'
```

Update:

I'm looking for a dynamic solution so I guess querying against INFORMATION_SCHEMA would be more appropriate.

This actually helps a bit because I'm looking to set it off from an update trigger, so I'll have one row at a time and I can query against the INFORMATION_SCHEMA for the main table checking datatypes to eliminate text, ntext and image that the generated tables, 'inserted' and 'deleted' choke on.

Solution: (updated: had to add some more code to return the one value)

```
-- passed in table name & schema
DECLARE @table_name nvarchar(100)
DECLARE @schema_name nvarchar(100)

-- set initial value
SET @table_name = 'my_table'
SET @schema_name = 'dbo'

-- Variable to hold query
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(MAX)
SET @sql = 'SELECT @row_stringOUT = '

-- Query columns meeting criteria and build query
SELECT
    -- Query as one string
    @sql = (@sql + '  ''  ' + COLUMN_NAME + ': '' + CASE WHEN ' + COLUMN_NAME + ' IS NULL THEN '''' WHEN ISDATE(' + COLUMN_NAME + ') = 1 THEN CONVERT(nvarchar(100), ' + COLUMN_NAME + ', 120) ELSE CAST(' + COLUMN_NAME + ' AS nvarchar(100)) END + ')
FROM 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE 
    table_schema = @schema_name
    AND
    table_name = @table_name
    AND
    -- Filter out unuseable data types
    data_type NOT IN ('text', 'ntext', 'image')

-- Trim extra character before FROM statement then add FROM statement
SELECT @sql = LEFT(@sql, LEN(@sql) - 1) + ' FROM ' + @table_name;

-- Execute Query
DECLARE @params nvarchar(MAX)
SET @params = N'@row_stringOUT ntext OUTPUT';

DECLARE @ret_value nvarchar(MAX)

EXEC sp_executesql
    @sql
    , @params
    , @row_stringOUT = @ret_value OUTPUT

SELECT @ret_value
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just concat the columns. if you want to get column names to you'll have to use some mix of dynamic sql, INFORMATION_SCHEMA views and querying...

```
SELECT  cast(ID as varchar(10)) + ' ' + [First Name] + ' ' + [Last Name] + ' ' + Color 
FROM    MyTable
```

Comment: I'm looking for a dynamic solution so I guess INFORMATION_SCHEMA is where it's at.

Answer (score 1):

`Select CAST(ID As Varchar(8)) + ' ' + [First Name] + ' ' + [Last Name] + ' ' + Color
From TheTable`

To get the verbose formatting you mentioned:

`Select 'ID: ' + CAST(ID As Varchar(8)) + ', First Name: ' + [First Name] + ', Last Name: ' + [Last Name] + ', Color: ' + Color
From TheTable`

Edit:  Now assuming ID is an integer autonumber.  Most likely the case, as ajdams points out.

Comment: +1 - Beat me to it.  The one thing I might add is that, if you want to copy and paste your results and you are working in SQL Server Management Studio, you can tell it to output the data as text.  You can also output to file if the dataset is large.

Comment: ajdams is right but you need only use a Cast to overcome the objection.

Answer (score 0):

Actually if ID has a data type of int the solution Patrick suggested will give you a conversion error. You will have to do something like this

SELECT CAST(ID AS varchar(10)) + ' ' + [first name] + ' ' + [last name + ' ' + color
FROM MYTABLE